# How to Add Country Code with Phone field on Contact Us Page Magento 2.4.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, contact-form

I want to add a country code with a phone field on the contact us page Magento 2.4.0. Can you help me there is any snippet or idea how to I'll add?

[image]

Looking forward to hearing from your side.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use below extension

https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input

1.Go to Magento 2 root directory

2.Enter following commands to install module:

```
 composer require maxmage/international-telephone-input
```

3.Enter following commands to enable module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable MaxMage_InternationalTelephoneInput
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Note: Input type name should be "telephone"